# divide background of line plot R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, dt

I would like to divide a line plot in two areas (left and right). I am ploting same historical values and predicting value and I am dreaming about having a different background for historical and predicted values. I prefer using the Plotly library.

Does anyone know if it is possible and how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `rect shape` to your `layout` which has the same dimensions as your measured and your predicted data. Either create two separate traces, one for the real data and one for the predicted, or use a merged trace.

**Two traces**

```
set.seed(42)

x <- sort(rnorm(25)) 
y <- x + rnorm(5)

predict(lm(y ~ x))
new_x <- seq(max(x) + 0.1, 5, 1)
new <- data.frame(x = new_x)
pred <- predict(lm(y ~ x), new, se.fit = TRUE)
new_y <- unname(pred$fit)

p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_trace(p, x = x, y = y, name = 'real', type = 'scatter', mode = 'scatter+lines', line = list(shape = 'spline'))
p <- add_trace(p, x = new_x, y = new_y, name = 'predicted', type = 'scatter', mode = 'scatter+lines', line = list(shape = 'spline'))


p <- layout(p,
            shapes = list(
              list(type = "rect",
                   fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.3,
                   x0 = min(x), x1 = max(x), xref = "x",
                   y0 = min(y), y1 = max(new_y), yref = "y"),
              list(type = "rect",
                   fillcolor = "red", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.2,
                   x0 = max(x), x1 = max(new_x), xref = "x",
                   y0 = min(y), y1 = max(new_y), yref = "y")))

p
```

[image]

**One trace**

```
set.seed(42)

x <- sort(rnorm(25)) 
y <- x + rnorm(5)

predict(lm(y ~ x))
new_x <- seq(max(x) + 0.1, 5, 1)
new <- data.frame(x = new_x)
pred <- predict(lm(y ~ x), new, se.fit = TRUE)
new_y <- unname(pred$fit)

all_x = c(x, new_x)
all_y = c(y, new_y)
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_trace(p, x = all_x, y = all_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'scatter+lines', line=list(shape='spline'))

p <- layout(p,
            shapes = list(
              list(type = "rect",
                   fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.3,
                   x0 = min(x), x1 = max(x), xref = "x",
                   y0 = min(y), y1 = max(new_y), yref = "y"),
              list(type = "rect",
                   fillcolor = "red", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.2,
                   x0 = max(x), x1 = max(new_x), xref = "x",
                   y0 = min(y), y1 = max(new_y), yref = "y")))

p
```

[image]